# How to process an array returned by a wsdl?

Tags: android, wsdl, ksoap2

I am using ksoap2 in order to extract an array of strings from a wsdl based webservice(for an android app). How do I process the returned array? I need those 3-4 lines of code which will let me save and use that returned array in my class. Thanks.

Comment: [what have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: I haven't tried anything as I am not clear on how to do it. But I am at the point where I know the web service should return a list of countries(I assume in the form of an array of strings).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String r = NameArray.columncount("userid", limitstart, loadNumber,loggername);
String temp = r.replaceAll(";\\s", ",").replaceAll("string=", " ")
                .replace("anyType{", "").replace(",}", "");
String[] fulname = temp.split(",\\s+");
```

'NameArray.columncount' is my function which gets the array from the wsdl(don't get confused in that)

step 1-
Here I am getting the array values returned from the wsdl in to a string called 'r'.In this case I am getting an array of numbers
Returned array string r looks like this

r ="anyType{string=10054; string=10055; string=10056; string=10035; string=10052; string=10036; string=10037; string=10038; }"

step 2-
Then creating a String variable called temp where I am removing all the unwanted characters using the replaceAll function.
after removing unwanted characters temp looks like this

temp="10054, 10055, 10056, 10035, 10052, 10036, 10037, 10038"

step3-
Finally created a string array called 'fulname' and split the modified string with ',\s'
Array fulname after split looks like this

fulname = [ 10054, 10055, 10056, 10035, 10052, 10036, 10037, 10038]

This will work fine because all the wsdl array return the same type of string with same unwanted characters

Hope you understood
Good Luck

Comment: Thanks for the quick response    . Is all this in a loop? And does the wsdl return string by string instead of a whole array?

Comment: Ok thanks so much man, I'll test this when I get home and post the result.

Comment: As I know(there may be other ways) you cannot return value as a whole array from wsdl, you can only get the returned array as a single string. it is best to get as a string and to process it your self to, create the array again.like i did.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still on this problem, you can check out this article which explain the whole procedure to parse arrays returned in KSOAP:
http://seesharpgears.blogspot.fr/2010/10/web-service-that-returns-array-of.html
Hope this answer to your question ;)